# Does Bragg's law take into account atom size? (And should it?)

Tags: optics, diffraction

Bragg's law explains wave diffraction and interaction when electromagnetic waves hit a lattice structure:

$$n \lambda = 2 d \sin \theta$$

See picture and details on Wikipedia.
[image]

I am wondering if the size of the atoms (modelled in the pictures as black dots) matters? In the derivation, the atom size is not mentioned anywhere, nor in the formula, so I guess it doesn't care. Should it, though? Or are they so negligibly small that this doesn't matter at all? Are there examples of the same lattice made of different molecules, and do they have the exact same diffraction pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The positions of the diffraction peaks do not depend on the size of the atoms. The peak positions are determined by the spacings of the crystal lattice and it does not matter what the atoms are or how big they are. That's why the atom size does not appear in the Bragg formula.

However the intensities of the lines, both absolute and relative, depend very strongly on the size of the atoms. X-rays scatter off electrons, so what is actually doing the scattering is the regular variation of electron density in the crystal. The scattering is stronger where the electron density is higher, i.e. near the nucleus, and weaker where electron density is lower, i.e. between atoms.

The variation of electron density over an atom is known as the [form factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_form_factor). relating the form factor so the scattering intensity is a somewhat involved calculation but is described in any textbook on X-ray scattering.